# How to get text file data through online php file.Is this possible in php?

Tags: php, text-files

I have text file that is located on my local computer. So I have another file of php that is located on my online server.

So I want to get data from that text file that is located my local server through my online uploaded php file.

Is this possible in php. If yes then what will be the php code ? I have no idea how to do this

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.

You have to upload the file through form from your local system to server with form input field, than you can read the uploaded file.The procedure is something similar. (Not tested)

You need to create one form with file upload element.

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="uploadedfile" id="uploadedfile" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Now from this form file input you can upload your local text file.

The php code for upload is like:

```
$target_path = "uploads/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

And than you can read the text file like:

```
$myFile = "filename_uploaded.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
fclose($fh);
echo $theData;
```